# Oracle select field in another record based on current record

Tags: sql, excel, oracle, odbc

I need to perform a single oracle SQL query that will return the value of a field from a different record if the record matches certain criteria from the current record. This data is pulled from an Oracle SQL DB into excel through an ODBC connection to generate reports. Currently I pull all data from the table and manipulate it in excel but the number of records has increased to such a degree that this is no longer a viable option. (roughly 1/4 million)

```
SOURCE TABLE
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|major |minor |step |currentUser |NextUser |comment            |stage |action  |timestamp |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|475   |13    |1    |jim         |bob      |request created    |QA    |submit  |12-19-2005|
|475   |13    |2    |bob         |james    |request approved   |RA    |accept  |12-20-2005|
|475   |13    |3    |james       |bob      |data submitted     |QA    |submit  |12-21-2005|
|475   |13    |4    |            |james    |rejected: thisISwhy|RA    |accept  |12-22-2005|
|475   |13    |5    |James       |bob      |data submitted     |QA    |submit  |12-23-2005|
|475   |13    |6    |            |jim      |data  approved     |SC    |complete|12-24-2005|
|475   |13    |6    |            |         |request closed     |SC    |closed  |12-24-2005|
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Basically, jim sends a request to james but bob approves or rejects every step along the way. There are 3 submits here so I only need 3 records but some of the data comes from data in a field from a different record. currently jim gets 1 submit and 0 rejections and james gets 2 submits and 1 rejection. HERE'S THE CATCH: If bob rejects james submission, the request can be reassigned to sally and the system that holds this data retroactively assgins sally as the nextUser on step 4 which would make it APPEAR that sally got a rejection, but it was james who submitted in error. In that case, jim,james, and sally all get 1 submit but james has 1 rejection. This is what I need it to output (the last 2 filds "1's" are counter flags for number of submits and rejects for the report)

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|major |minor |step |submiter |QA_rep|comment            |timestamp  |submit |reject |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|475   |13    |1    |jim      |bob   |thing created      |12-19-2005 |1      |       |
|475   |13    |3    |james    |bob   |rejected: thisISwhy|12-22-2005 |1      |1      |
|475   |13    |5    |james    |bob   |data approved      |12-22-2005 |1      |       |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you could update your sample input and output data to demonstrate the case where a rejected submission is assigned to someone else.

Answer (score 0):

I've taken a guess at some of the logic (will a rejected row always have a comment starting with "rejected:"? Also, would the action for a rejected row really be "accepted"? I've also made some assumptions that for a submitted row, the "nextuser" is the qa user; you may need to add in some additional case statements if this isn't always the case. I've taken a guess at your case where a row is rejected and assigned to someone else.

If any of my assumptions are incorrect, hopefully you'll be able to amend my query to suit your purposes.

```
with source_table as (select 475 major, 13 minor, 1 step, 'jim' currentuser, 'bob' nextuser, 'request created' request_comment, 'QA'  stage, 'submit' action, to_date('19/12/2005', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dt from dual union all
                      select 475 major, 13 minor, 2 step, 'bob' currentuser, 'james' nextuser, 'request approved' request_comment, 'RA'  stage, 'accept' action, to_date('20/12/2005', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dt from dual union all
                      select 475 major, 13 minor, 3 step, 'james' currentuser, 'bob' nextuser, 'data submitted' request_comment, 'QA'  stage, 'submit' action, to_date('21/12/2005', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dt from dual union all
                      select 475 major, 13 minor, 4 step, null currentuser, 'james' nextuser, 'rejected: thisISwhy' request_comment, 'RA'  stage, 'accept' action, to_date('22/12/2005', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dt from dual union all
                      select 475 major, 13 minor, 5 step, 'james' currentuser, 'bob' nextuser, 'data submitted' request_comment, 'QA'  stage, 'submit' action, to_date('23/12/2005', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dt from dual union all
                      select 475 major, 13 minor, 6 step, null currentuser, 'jim' nextuser, 'data approved' request_comment, 'SC'  stage, 'complete' action, to_date('24/12/2005', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dt from dual union all
                      select 475 major, 13 minor, 6 step, null currentuser, null nextuser, 'request closed' request_comment, 'SC'  stage, 'closed' action, to_date('24/12/2005', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dt from dual union all
                      select 475 major, 14 minor, 1 step, 'jim' currentuser, 'bob' nextuser, 'request created' request_comment, 'QA'  stage, 'submit' action, to_date('19/12/2005', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dt from dual union all
                      select 475 major, 14 minor, 2 step, 'bob' currentuser, 'james' nextuser, 'request approved' request_comment, 'RA'  stage, 'accept' action, to_date('20/12/2005', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dt from dual union all
                      select 475 major, 14 minor, 3 step, 'james' currentuser, 'bob' nextuser, 'data submitted' request_comment, 'QA'  stage, 'submit' action, to_date('21/12/2005', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dt from dual union all
                      select 475 major, 14 minor, 4 step, null currentuser, 'sally' nextuser, 'rejected: thisISwhy' request_comment, 'RA'  stage, 'accept' action, to_date('22/12/2005', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dt from dual union all
                      select 475 major, 14 minor, 5 step, 'sally' currentuser, 'bob' nextuser, 'data submitted' request_comment, 'QA'  stage, 'submit' action, to_date('23/12/2005', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dt from dual union all
                      select 475 major, 14 minor, 6 step, null currentuser, 'jim' nextuser, 'data approved' request_comment, 'SC'  stage, 'complete' action, to_date('24/12/2005', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dt from dual union all
                      select 475 major, 14 minor, 6 step, null currentuser, null nextuser, 'request closed' request_comment, 'SC'  stage, 'closed' action, to_date('24/12/2005', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dt from dual),
              res as (select major,
                             minor,
                             step,
                             currentuser,
                             nextuser,
                             request_comment,
                             dt,
                             stage,
                             action,
                             lead(request_comment) over (partition by major, minor order by step) next_comment,
                             case when lead(request_comment) over (partition by major, minor order by step) like 'rejected:%' then 1 end rejected
                      from   source_table)
select major,
       minor,
       step,
       currentuser submitter,
       nextuser qa_rep,
       next_comment request_comment,
       dt,
       1 submit,
       rejected
from   res
where  action = 'submit';

     MAJOR      MINOR       STEP SUBMITTER QA_REP REQUEST_COMMENT     DT             SUBMIT   REJECTED
---------- ---------- ---------- --------- ------ ------------------- ---------- ---------- ----------
       475         13          1 jim       bob    request approved    19/12/2005          1           
       475         13          3 james     bob    rejected: thisISwhy 21/12/2005          1          1
       475         13          5 james     bob    data approved       23/12/2005          1           
       475         14          1 jim       bob    request approved    19/12/2005          1           
       475         14          3 james     bob    rejected: thisISwhy 21/12/2005          1          1
       475         14          5 sally     bob    data approved       23/12/2005          1
```